# SlimDX 11 Depth Buffer issues

Tags: c#, slimdx, directx-11

I am getting an issue with SlimDX March SDK (For DXSDK11 June 2010 I believe). The problem is that whenever I turn the attach the depth view to the output merger state I don't get any output on the screen. I have compared my code with DX11 samples and it does seem to be correct. I have tried all sorts of flags and formats for the depth test (including always passing etc.) but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate if anyone can spot a mistake. Here is the code. Here are the steps:

1. Initialize the back buffer:

   ```
           D3DDevice device;
       SwapChain swapChain;

       /// Create the swap chain
       SwapChainDescription desc = new SwapChainDescription()
       {
           BufferCount = 1,
           ModeDescription = new ModeDescription 
           { 
               Width = ContextSettings.Width, 
               Height = ContextSettings.Height, 
               RefreshRate = new SlimDX.Rational(ContextSettings.RefreshRate, 1), 
               Format = ContextSettings.BufferFormat,
           },
           IsWindowed = !ContextSettings.FullScreen,
           OutputHandle = WindowHandle,
           SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
           SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
           Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
       };

       FeatureLevel[] featureLevels = new FeatureLevel[] { FeatureLevel.Level_11_0, FeatureLevel.Level_10_1 };
       DriverType driverType = DriverType.Hardware;

       D3DDevice.CreateWithSwapChain(driverType, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug, featureLevels, desc, out device, out swapChain);

       Device = device;
       SwapChain = swapChain;

       /// Setup window association
       Factory factory = swapChain.GetParent<Factory>();
       factory.SetWindowAssociation(WindowHandle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

       /// Setup back buffers and render target views
       RenderBuffer = DXTexture2D.FromSwapChain<DXTexture2D>(swapChain, 0);
       RenderView = new RenderTargetView(Device, RenderBuffer);
   ```
2. Then initialize the depth buffer:

   ```
           Format depthFormat = Format.D32_Float;
       Texture2DDescription depthBufferDesc = new Texture2DDescription 
       {
           ArraySize = 1,
           BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
           CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
           Format = depthFormat,
           Height = width,
           Width = height,
           MipLevels = 1,
           OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
           SampleDescription = new SampleDescription( 1, 0 ),
           Usage = ResourceUsage.Default
       };

       DepthBuffer = new DXTexture2D(Device, depthBufferDesc);

       DepthStencilViewDescription dsViewDesc = new DepthStencilViewDescription
       {
           ArraySize = 0,
           Format = depthFormat,
           Dimension = DepthStencilViewDimension.Texture2D,
           MipSlice = 0,
           Flags = 0,
           FirstArraySlice = 0
       };

       DepthView = new DepthStencilView(Device, DepthBuffer, dsViewDesc);

       DepthStencilStateDescription dsStateDesc = new DepthStencilStateDescription()
       {
           IsDepthEnabled = true,
           IsStencilEnabled = false,
           DepthWriteMask = DepthWriteMask.All,
           DepthComparison = Comparison.Less,
       };

       DepthState = DepthStencilState.FromDescription(Device, dsStateDesc);
   ```
3. Setup the render targets:

   ```
       DeviceContext.OutputMerger.DepthStencilState = DepthState;
       DeviceContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(DepthView, RenderView);
       DeviceContext.Rasterizer.SetViewports(new Viewport(0, 0, ContextSettings.Width, ContextSettings.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f));

       Clear();
   ```

As soon as I remove DepthView from OutputMerger.SetTargets I start seeing images on the screen (without the depth test of course) and vice-versa otherwise.

Comment: Have you looked at the debug output that DirectX will give you to see if there are any errors or warnings listed? Also try taking a look using PIX to see exactly what's going on with your geometry.

Comment: You're initializing the depth stencil view exactly the same way I do it. Only difference is the format I use is Format.D24_UNorm_S8_UInt. Could you try that and see if it works?

EDIT: Oh and I'm not using a DepthStencilState at all. Can you try commenting that out to see if that's where the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that in the depthBufferDesc, I was passing width to the Height variable and height to the Width. This was creating the two render targets with different dimensions which was breaking it down.